# SQL Format $ and Rounding

Tags: sql, oracle, dollar-sign

I'm trying to display the title, ISBN, Cost and category where the category has the least amount of books in it, while also trying to add a "$" in front of the output for cost while trying to round it to two decimal places.

Example for category =

```
Technology = 4
Family = 3
Sports = 2
Business = 4
```

In this case I want the output to display category Sports

```
Select TITLE, ISBN,
Round( '$' + CAST(COST AS VARCHAR(15)) COST, 2),
 CATEGORY
From BOOKS
GROUP By category
HAVING Category = ((Select Min(Category)
From (Select Count(Category) AS Category)
From BOOKS
Group By Category)
;
```

Comment: That kind of formatting is better done in the application (GUI), not in the SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle uses `||` for string concatenation. To get the categories with min counts you can use inline views, one to get the counts and the other to get the minimum count and `join` with the original table.

```
select b.TITLE, b.ISBN,
'$' || TO_CHAR(ROUND(b.COST,2)) cost, b.CATEGORY
From BOOKS b
join (select category,count(*) cnt from books group by category) ct
on b.category = ct.category
join (select min(cnt) mincnt 
      from (select count(*) cnt from books group by category)) minct
on ct.cnt = minct.mincnt
```

Comment: what if you have multiple categories with the same amount of books?

Comment: do you want to select all books for a category which have minimum number of rows in the table?

Comment: example if business had 1 and sports had 1, I'd want to display both. Sorry - I should've made myself more clearer in the original post

Comment: It's not just "Oracle" that uses `||` for string concatenation. The `||` is part of the SQL standard specification.